# Using git-gui on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I have Git installed with Homebrew.

However, `git-gui` doesn't seem to come stock in `/usr/local/bin`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608076) suggests I should create an alias to `usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui`, but this file doesn't exist.

The only executable I can find is located in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4/share/git-gui
```

Now this is the alias I used. However, if I ever update Git, I'll have to relink it.

How do I get a permanent reference to `git-gui`?

Comment: NB that you need git installed *from hombrew* (not the default) if you want git gui to work at all.  For me, after doing that, git gui just works, no extra work needed... (Just run "git gui") FWIW

Comment: "I have Git installed with Homebrew."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/usr/local/opt/` contains symlinks to the directories in `/usr/local/Cellar/`:

```
$ ll /usr/local/opt/git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lauri  admin    19B Oct 11 17:07 /usr/local/opt/git -> ../Cellar/git/1.8.4
$ ll /usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui
-rwxr-xr-x  2 lauri  admin   205B Sep 18 23:28 /usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui
```

Check the file exists, then add something like this to ~/.gitconfig:

```
[alias] 
gui = !sh -c '/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui'
```

Answer (score 14):

Since version 2.25.0_1 of the `git` formula on Homebrew, the `git gui` functionality has been separated out into the `git-gui` formula. See the following pull request for background on this change: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/49136

Because of this, a better solution for to fix a broken `git gui` **on a Homebrew installation of `git`** is to run:

```
brew install git-gui
```

Comment: +1 i forgot i can run using `git gui` instead of `git-gui`